# How do I change css style in SugarCRM 7

Tags: sugarcrm

In SugarCRM 6 we could modify css styles by placing the custom css style in a file called style.css under custom/themes/Sugar/css. Is there a similar way for doing this in SugarCRM 7 ?

The style I wish to change is in a css file located in cache/themes/clients/base/default/sugar_xxx.css. What is the upgrade-safe way of modifying this ?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to follow the instructions available in Administration > Styleguide > Core Elements > Custom Theme Variables (http:// YourSugarUrl/#Styleguide/docs/base_theme) and to add the file “custom/themes/custom.less” + a Quick Repair & Rebuild

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't make much out of using the .less files. I could get SidecarTheme.php to fetch variables from the file custom/themes/clients/base/default/variables.less. But couldn't see any effect on the css file. So I just created a file custom/include/MVC/View/tpls/sidecar.tpl with its contents as `{include file='include/MVC/View/tpls/sidecar.tpl'} 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom/themes/clients/base/default/style.css"/>
` and added the css inside style.css. Now it's working okay. Thanks for your pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you rebuild! If you don't rebuild the changes won't take.